# UILocalNotification in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, nsuserdefaults, uilocalnotification

My app uses `UILocalNotification`. On some action from a user, say press of a button, I need to cancel ALL UILocalNotifications, which were set by my application. I have found a solution, however this didn't work out in all cases. The solution was like this:

```
let scheduledNotifications = UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications
scheduledNotifications?.forEach {
    UIApplication.shared.cancelLocalNotification($0)
}
```

Trying to fix the bug (one or several notifications were not cancelled), I've found a shorter solution, which was simply this:

```
UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

The latter one seems to work just fine.
What don't I understand? Is there really some difference in functionality of these two snippets of code?

Accompanying question:
1) Specifically, notification set by another version of the app was not cancelled by the first solution.
2) What is happening on rolling out a new version of app? I mean, what about UserDefaults and LocalNotifications set by previous version of the app? Are these kept between different version of the app? What happens with the app on update from App Store?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!